# How to create a column with specific timestamp?

Tags: oracle

```
create table my_table(
    id NUMBER(5),
    my_date  TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    constraint customers_pk primary key (id)
    );
```

I want to make the TIMESTAMP like this: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
and what does the number in brackets of timestamp mean?

Comment: See the manual for the details on what that number means: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#i53219

Comment: Did you mean _with a specific timestamp **format**_? Formatting is applied in the reporting tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`timestamp`s don't have a format.

They are stored in a binary representation. If you want to display the values in a specific format, use `to_char()` to format it as a string or do that in your application.

Comment: and what does the number in brackets of timestamp means?

Comment: @eeeponto: see the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#i53219

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, you cannot change its format on CREATE TABLE. 
on querying if you use proper NLS Format, you wont deal with this again and again